# python variables are not in index

Tags: python, indexing, boolean, jupyter

I have the following jupyter notebook code and error:

```
stats = create_stats_df('epl_data.csv')
stats.head(3)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6352c53ac97c> in <module>
      1 # This includes only the typical soccer stats, like home corners, home shots on target etc.
----> 2 stats = create_stats_df('epl_data.csv')
      3 stats.head(3)

~\Documents\Prive\Python\Projects\Betting\new_model\data_preparation_functions2.py in create_stats_df(path)
     63                            'Over05sh', 'Over15sh', 'homedc', 'awaydc','homeawaydc']
     64 
---> 65                 stats = df[stats_cols].copy()
     66                 stats = stats.reindex(columns=stats_cols)
     67                 return stats

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2910             if is_iterator(key):
   2911                 key = list(key)
-> 2912             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2913 
   2914         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1252             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1253 
-> 1254         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
   1255         return keyarr, indexer
   1256 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1302             if raise_missing:
   1303                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1304                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1305 
   1306             # we skip the warning on Categorical

KeyError: "['Over05fh', 'Over15', 'Over35', 'Over15fh', 'Over05sh', 'Over15sh'] not in index"
```

The create_stats_df is from a python file, which I important like this:

```
from data_preparation_functions2 import *
```

When I look in the data_preparation_functions2 file, I have the following code for the create_stats_df function:

```
def create_stats_df(path):
        df = (pd.read_csv(path, dtype={'season': str})
                        .assign(Date=lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df.Date))
                        .pipe(lambda df: df.dropna(thresh=len(df) - 2, axis=1))  # Drop cols with NAs
                        .dropna(axis=0)  # Drop rows with NAs
                        .sort_values('Date')
                        .reset_index(drop=True)
                        .assign(gameId=lambda df: list(df.index + 1),
                                bttsn=lambda df: df.apply(
                                              lambda row: 1 if row.FTHG == 0 or row.FTAG == 0 else 0, axis="columns"),
                                over15=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.FTHG + row.FTAG) > 1 else 0,
                                                           axis="columns"),
                                Over25=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.FTHG + row.FTAG) > 2 else 0,
                                                           axis="columns"),
                                over35=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.FTHG + row.FTAG) > 3 else 0,
                                                           axis="columns"),
                                over05fh=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.HTHG + row.HTAG) > 0 else 0,
                                                             axis="columns"),
                                over15fh=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: 1 if (row.HTHG + row.HTAG) > 1 else 0,
                                                             axis="columns"),
                                over05sh=lambda df: df.apply(
                                    lambda row: 1 if (row.FTHG + row.FTAG) - (row.HTHG + row.HTAG) > 0 else 0,
                                    axis="columns"),
                                over15sh=lambda df: df.apply(
                                    lambda row: 1 if row.FTHG > row.FTAG or row.FTHG == row.FTAG else 0,
                                    axis="columns"),
                                homedc=lambda df: df.apply(
                                    lambda row: 1 if row.FTHG > row.FTAG or row.FTHG == row.FTAG else 0,
                                    axis="columns"),
                                awaydc=lambda df: df.apply(
                                    lambda row: 1 if row.FTHG < row.FTAG or row.FTHG == row.FTAG else 0,
                                    axis="columns"),
                                homeawaydc=lambda df: df.apply(
                                    lambda row: 1 if row.FTHG > row.FTAG or row.FTHG < row.FTAG else 0, axis="columns")))


        
        stats_cols = ['gameId', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG', 'HTHG', 'HTAG', 'HS', 'AS',
                                    'HST', 'AST', 'HF', 'AF', 'HC', 'AC', 'HY', 'AY', 'HR', 'AR', 'bttsn', 'Over15', 'Over25', 'Over35',
                           'Over05fh','Over15fh',
                           'Over05sh', 'Over15sh', 'homedc', 'awaydc','homeawaydc']
        
        stats = df[stats_cols].copy()
        stats = stats.reindex(columns=stats_cols)
        return stats
```

Does anyone know why I get the error in my jupyter notebook? Why are the 'Over15' etc not in the index?

The strange thing is that 'bttsn', 'homedc', 'awaydc', 'homeawaydc' are in the index.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
stats = stats.reindex(stats_cols)
```

instead of

```
stats = stats.reindex(columns=stats_cols)
```

A quick exemple to illustrate :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
df
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
df.reindex(columns=['A','B'])
    A   B
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
df.reindex(['A','B'])
    0   1
A NaN NaN
B NaN NaN
```

Comment: I still have the same error. The weird part is that only some of the variables are not in the index, whereas other are in the index and return without a problem.